# Possibility of adding a directory in Python-nested?

Tags: python

What is the best way to check if the directory a file is going to be written to exists, and if not, how to create the directory using Python?

Does a flag exists as "open", that makes this happen automatically?

Comment: No, `open` didn't create a directory if that not exist. For creating a directory if not exist use @mx0 solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `makedirs` from `os` module:

```
os.makedirs(DIRECTORY, exist_ok=True)
```

This will create a directory if it doesn't exist.